# Memory Leaks in C with nested structures

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks

I'm writing a basic LSTM network in C without the usage of calloc/malloc/free.

Although it terminates, I get many memory errors when I run it.

I trimmed the code down as much as I could so it still reproduces some of them.

I have marked down with comments where the memory errors occur in this trimmed down version.

Here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 150
#define LSTM_SIZE 100
#define MAX_NODES 4

double sigmoid(double x){                    //
    double r;                                //
    r = 1 / (1 + exp(-x));                   //
    return r;                                //
}                                            //MEMORY 
                                             //ERRORS
double DP(double A[], double B[], int l) {   //OCCUR 
    double result = 0;                       //WHEN 
    int i;                                   //THESE 2
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {                //FUNCTIONS 
        result += A[i] * B[i];               //ARE CALLED
    }                                        //
                                             //
    return result;                           //
}

struct LstmParam{                          //   
    double wg[LSTM_SIZE][ARRAY_SIZE];      //   
    double wi[LSTM_SIZE][ARRAY_SIZE];      //   
    double wf[LSTM_SIZE][ARRAY_SIZE];      //FIRST  
    double wo[LSTM_SIZE][ARRAY_SIZE];      //DOUBLY
    double bg[LSTM_SIZE];                  //NESTED 
    double bi[LSTM_SIZE];                  //STRUCT
    double bf[LSTM_SIZE];                  //   
    double bo[LSTM_SIZE];                  //   
};                                         //

void init_LstmParam(struct LstmParam *param){                                //
    int i,j;                                                                 //
    double a = 0, b=0.1;                                                     //
    for (i=0;i<LSTM_SIZE;i++){                                               //
        for (j=0;j<ARRAY_SIZE;j++){                                          //
            param->wg[i][j] = ((double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX))*(b-a)+a;   //INITIALIZATION
            param->wi[i][j] = ((double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX))*(b-a)+a;   //OF 
            param->wf[i][j] = ((double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX))*(b-a)+a;   //FIRST
            param->wo[i][j] = ((double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX))*(b-a)+a;   //DOUBLY
        }                                                                    //NESTED
        param->bg[i] = ((double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX))*(b-a)+a;          //STRUCT
        param->bi[i] = ((double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX))*(b-a)+a;          //
        param->bf[i] = ((double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX))*(b-a)+a;          //
        param->bo[i] = ((double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX))*(b-a)+a;          //
    }                                                                        //
}                                                                            //

struct LstmState{          //
    double g[LSTM_SIZE];   //
    double i[LSTM_SIZE];   //SECOND
    double f[LSTM_SIZE];   //DOUBLY
    double o[LSTM_SIZE];   //NESTED
    double s[LSTM_SIZE];   //STRUCT
    double h[LSTM_SIZE];   //
};                         //

void init_LstmState(struct LstmState *state){   //
    int i;                                      //
    for (i=0;i<LSTM_SIZE;i++){                  //INITIALIZATION
        state->g[i]=0;                          //OF 
        state->i[i]=0;                          //SECOND
        state->f[i]=0;                          //DOUBLY
        state->o[i]=0;                          //NESETED
        state->s[i]=0;                          //STRUCT
        state->h[i]=0;                          //
    }                                           //
}                                               //

struct LstmNode{              //
    double xc[ARRAY_SIZE];    //NESTED
    struct LstmParam param;   //STRUCT
    struct LstmState state;   //
};                            //

void init_LstmNode(struct LstmNode *node){   //INITIALIZTION OF
    init_LstmParam(&node->param);            //STRUCTS WITHIN
    init_LstmState(&node->state);            //NESTED
}                                            //STRUCT

void bottom_data_is(double x[ARRAY_SIZE-LSTM_SIZE], double s_prev[LSTM_SIZE], double h_prev[LSTM_SIZE], struct LstmNode *node){ 
    int i;                                                          
    for (i=0;i<ARRAY_SIZE;i++){                                                 
        if (i<ARRAY_SIZE-LSTM_SIZE){                                                
            node->xc[i]=x[i];                                                   
        } else {                                                        
            node->xc[i]=h_prev[i-ARRAY_SIZE+LSTM_SIZE];                                     
        }                                                           
    }
    for (i=0;i<LSTM_SIZE;i++){
        node->state.g[i]=                                                       //                                                        
        tanh(DP(node->param.wg[i],node->xc,ARRAY_SIZE)+node->param.bg[i]);      //MEMORY 
        node->state.i[i]=                                                       //ERRORS
        sigmoid(DP(node->param.wi[i],node->xc,ARRAY_SIZE)+node->param.bi[i]);   //OCCUR
        node->state.f[i]=                                                       //HERE
        sigmoid(DP(node->param.wf[i],node->xc,ARRAY_SIZE)+node->param.bf[i]);   //
        node->state.o[i]=                                                       //
        sigmoid(DP(node->param.wo[i],node->xc,ARRAY_SIZE)+node->param.bo[i]);   //
    }
}

struct LstmNetwork{                                     //
    struct LstmNode *lstm_node_list[MAX_NODES];         //BIG
    double x_list[MAX_NODES][ARRAY_SIZE-LSTM_SIZE];     //STRUCT
} n={};                                                 //

void x_list_add(double x[ARRAY_SIZE-LSTM_SIZE],int idx, struct LstmNetwork *network,int iter){
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<ARRAY_SIZE-LSTM_SIZE;i++){
        network->x_list[idx][i] = x[i];
    }
    if (iter==0){
        struct LstmNode node;
        init_LstmNode(&node);
        network->lstm_node_list[idx]=&node;
    }   
    double s_prev[LSTM_SIZE],h_prev[LSTM_SIZE];
    if (idx==0){
        for (i=0;i<LSTM_SIZE;i++){
            s_prev[i]=0;
            h_prev[i]=0;
        }
        bottom_data_is(x,s_prev,h_prev,network->lstm_node_list[idx]);  // MEMORY ERRORS INSIDE HERE
    } else{
        for (i=0;i<LSTM_SIZE;i++){
            s_prev[i] = network->lstm_node_list[idx-1]->state.s[i];
            h_prev[i] = network->lstm_node_list[idx-1]->state.h[i];
        }
        bottom_data_is(x,s_prev,h_prev,network->lstm_node_list[idx]);  // MEMORY ERRORS INSIDE HERE
    }
}

int main() {
    srand(1);
    double y_list[MAX_NODES] = {-0.5,0.2,0.1,-0.5};
    int i;
    double input_val_arr[MAX_NODES][ARRAY_SIZE-LSTM_SIZE];
    for (i=0;i<ARRAY_SIZE-LSTM_SIZE;i++){
        input_val_arr[0][i]=((double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX));
        input_val_arr[1][i]=((double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX));
        input_val_arr[2][i]=((double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX));
        input_val_arr[3][i]=((double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX));
    }
    int cur_iter,ind;
    for (cur_iter=0;cur_iter<LSTM_SIZE;cur_iter++){
        for (ind=0;ind<4;ind++){
            x_list_add(input_val_arr[ind],ind,&n,cur_iter); // MEMORY ERRORS INSIDE
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the program I got a big structure with nested structures within, of total size of about 4MB.
I had memory leak issues when running it on Windows and it never terminated. I later found out it was because Windows had about 1MB stack size.

I later changed to Linux and it run all the way to the end but I still have memory errors.

I've tried many iterations of declaring variables and structures globally or locally, making them static or not, declaring the nested structures locally ,inside the others, or globally by themselves, but nothing seems to fix the errors.

I detect the memory errors by using `valgrind`.

The errors are:

"Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)"

and "Use of uninitialised value of size 8"

The structures in this version are smaller in size since the programm is trimmed down. Naturally, the full version has even more memory errors. But if I figure out what causes those ones I think I can fix them all, maybe.

Comment: Are you talking about memory _leaks_ or memory _corruption_? Please make up your mind and [edit].

Comment: I'd add code that checks that none of your array indices gets out of bounds

Comment: Re "*I detect the memory errors by using valgrind.*", Well, what are they? What are the error messages and the associated line numbers?

Comment: @ikegami I edited the post with the error messages. As for the line numbers, I've marked them with comments in the code, in the line that they happen.

Comment: Where's the rest of the message? (The  line number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in accessing data allocated on the stack after it went out-of-scope.

In the following snippet, `node` is created on the stack. A pointer to `node` is stored in `network->lstm_node_list[idx]`:

```
if (iter==0){
    struct LstmNode node;
    init_LstmNode(&node);
    network->lstm_node_list[idx]=&node;
}
```

When the function `x_list_add` (which contains this snippet) returns, `node` is no longer in scope. Accessing this data (for example, when `iter` is not 0) is undefined behavior.

For reference: [An object is referred to outside of its lifetime (6.2.4)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.2.4)

Comment: Thanks I added a 'static' in front and it fixed all errors.

Comment: Making `node` static will solve the undefined behavior, but there will only be a *single* `node`. `network->lstm_node_list[0]`, `network->lstm_node_list[1]`, `network->lstm_node_list[2]` and `network->lstm_node_list[3]` will all point to the same data.

Comment: If you really cannot use dynamic allocation (such as `malloc`), please change `lstm_node_list` to be an array of `struct LstmNode` instead of an array of *pointers* to `struct LstmNode`.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's true. I will figure out a way to solve this. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Example with an array of nodes instead of pointers to nodes: https://godbolt.org/z/xqKE9KxjT

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide the error message, and I don't have access to `valgrind` at the moment, so I ran a version compiled with `-fsanitize=address`. Basically the same as `valgrind`. Aside from a few warnings (from `-Wall, -Wextra -pendantic`) that seemed harmless, I got

```
==1==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-scope on address 0x7fff9c0aa740 at pc 0x000000401a98 bp 0x7fff9c0a9f50 sp 0x7fff9c0a9f48
WRITE of size 8 at 0x7fff9c0aa740 thread T0
    #0 0x401a97 in bottom_data_is /app/example.c:89
    #1 0x4022ca in x_list_add /app/example.c:127
    #2 0x40285a in main /app/example.c:151
    #3 0x7f58c242c082 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x24082) (BuildId: 1878e6b475720c7c51969e69ab2d276fae6d1dee)
    #4 0x40113d in _start (/app/output.s+0x40113d) (BuildId: 9bcd96d370f68c7e3d7f3b83f1157ea4326c10ca)
```

This is the result of this error:

```c
{
    struct LstmNode node;
    init_LstmNode(&node);
    network->lstm_node_list[idx]=&node;
}
```

You're creating a pointer to a variable that immediately goes out of scope. This pointer isn't valid.

You could allocate memory on the heap using `malloc`, but you could also simply change

```c
struct LstmNetwork{
    struct LstmNode *lstm_node_list[MAX_NODES];
    double x_list[MAX_NODES][ARRAY_SIZE-LSTM_SIZE];
} n = { 0 };
```

to

```c
struct LstmNetwork{
    struct LstmNode lstm_node_list[MAX_NODES];
    double x_list[MAX_NODES][ARRAY_SIZE-LSTM_SIZE];
} n = { 0 };
```

(You'll need to change two instances of `a[idx]` to `a + idx`, and two instances of `->` to `.` to match.)

---

No other errors reported once this is fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can't use malloc, so I added a 'static' instead in front and it fixed all errors.

Comment: No, that's completely wrong. If you use static, you will create one and exactly one node. All your pointers will be to the same single node.  See updated answer.